# Is there any limit or problems with Wordpress Flynt Theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have been reviewing about WordPress [Flynt Theme](https://flyntwp.com/) a week ago.

I am going to develop a complex wordpress site by using Flynt. But I am not sure that Flynt will work without any doubt and has any conflict with famous Wordpress Plugins such as SEO plugins.

Comment: This question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow - a chatroom would be best for this. It's either opinion-based or asking for polling or requires clarity. One person will say the theme is great, another person might say the theme didn't work for them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm one of the core contributors of Flynt. [We](https://bleech.de) are using Flynt for all our custom designed WordPress projects ourselves, may it be [rather straight forward websites](https://www.mockupworld.co/), or [more complex ones](https://www.beumergroup.com/).

As a general rule, we try to avoid using too many plugins in our projects to avoid compatibility and security issues. We're also making limited use of WYSIWYGs and shortcodes, but rely on custom fields with [ACF Pro](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/) instead. Everything revolves around custom built components.

We're of course using popular plugins like [Yoast SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/), [Contact Form 7](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/), and [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/). But Yoast will require [ACF Content Analysis for Yoast SEO](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/acf-content-analysis-for-yoast-seo/) as a plugin for the backend to make things work. This will be similar for other plugins which are scanning `the_content()` to add functionality, as the component architecture is independent from `the_content()`.

I'm sure Flynt will work like a charm for you if you love custom development, but you might run into issues if you're heavily relying on plugins to add frontend functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. it's very helpful. I like to develop a wp theme from scratch. if then, I can make very optimized/clean/fast speed site. if any issue, can I also have some helps from you?

Comment: I recently found Flynt, and it's interesting to me because I recently started developing something similar myself - a library of reusable common frontend sections, based on ACF. I was using NPM for build tools (such as BrowserSync), and there are SCSS mixins and variables which makes it easy to update style for each new client... This approach speeded up our build process like 5x times, and made possible for us to sell custom-coded, stable, ACF themes to small clients with very limited budgets, who would normally probably get buggy page builder elementor site for that money. Anyway, thumbs up.